# Conceptual problem with the method of characteristics

Tags: derivatives, partial-differential-equations, characteristics

A first order linear PDE of the form $$a(x,y)u_{x}+b(x,y)u_{y}=c(x,y)$$ can be solved (under some conditions) using the method of characteristics. This method transforms the PDE above into two ODE's, namely $$  \frac{dx}{dy}=\frac{a}{b}\\  ~\frac{du}{dy}=\frac{c}{b}.$$

Bearing in mind that $u$ is a function of *two* variables, $x$ and $y$, what does $\dfrac{du}{dy}$ mean in the second ODE? Put differently, do we consider $u$ to be a function of $y$ only in the second ODE? Isn't this inconsistent since we know that $u$ also depends on $x$?

Comment: Where did you encounter this formulation of the method?

Comment: Normally, the method of characteristics introduces a curve parametrization, and differentials are total derivatives w.r.t. the parameter (see [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics))

Comment: @joriki I found this specific form in this [lecture](http://math.iisc.ernet.in/~prasad/prasad/Linear_Quasi.pdf) (page $15$). But now I have to admit I am a bit suspicious about it, I didn't find this form in the other books/articles I read.

Comment: They are different (but equivalent) presentations of  the method of characteristics. The ODEs that you mention are the Charpit-Lagrange equations. $$\frac{dx}{a(x,y)}=\frac{dy}{b(x,y)}=\frac{du}{c(x,y)}=dt$$. Sometimes $dt$ is loosly forgotten. The system of ODEs isn't valid everywhere but only on the characteristic curves which are parametrized. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics